Significant performance differences for 'ORDER BY x LIMIT 1' and 'ORDER BY x LIMIT 2'
I've got the following table:



name
type




id
PrimaryKey, UUID, Unique


test_id
ForeignKey, UUID, Indexed


created_at
DateTime+TZ, Indexed



  2 418 139 Distinct rows (test_id)
283 036 392 Distinct rows (created_at)
283 085 093 Total rows

Now I want to get some rows for a specific test_id, ordered by created_at.
As both columns are indexed, I assumed that the query should be quite fast.
However, I've seen a dramatic decrease in performance when running with LIMIT 1 vs. any other limits:
With LIMIT 2:
EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE SELECT "my_table"."id" FROM "my_table" WHERE ("my_table"."test_id" = '00018843-d632-42d4-b832-cf9d6df8e454'::uuid) ORDER BY "my_table"."created_at" ASC LIMIT 2;
                                                                                         QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=13137.72..13137.72 rows=2 width=56) (actual time=0.033..0.034 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: id, identifier, type, created_at
   ->  Sort  (cost=13137.72..13145.82 rows=3242 width=56) (actual time=0.033..0.033 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: id, created_at
         Sort Key: my_table.created_at
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Index Scan using my_table_test_id_d24b61ed on public.my_table  (cost=0.57..13105.30 rows=3242 width=56) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
               Output: id, created_at
               Index Cond: (my_table.test_id = '00018843-d632-42d4-b832-cf9d6df8e454'::uuid)
 Query Identifier: 5848686225449084285
 Planning Time: 0.093 ms
 Execution Time: 0.065 ms
(12 rows)

With LIMIT 1:
EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE SELECT "my_table"."id" FROM "my_table" WHERE ("my_table"."test_id" = '00018843-d632-42d4-b832-cf9d6df8e454'::uuid) ORDER BY "my_table"."created_at" ASC LIMIT 1;
                                                                                             QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.57..10735.90 rows=1 width=56) (actual time=73459.135..73459.135 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: id, created_at
   ->  Index Scan using my_table_created_at_231d382e on public.my_table  (cost=0.57..34803947.27 rows=3242 width=56) (actual time=73459.134..73459.134 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: id, created_at
         Filter: (my_table.test_id = '00018843-d632-42d4-b832-cf9d6df8e454'::uuid)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 110868840
 Query Identifier: 5848686225449084285
 Planning Time: 0.085 ms
 Execution Time: 73459.155 ms
(9 rows)

As you can see, running with LIMIT 1 takes significant more time than running with LIMIT 2.
Running with any other limit, e.g. LIMIT 10 or LIMIT 100, has the same performance then LIMIT 2.
I can see why the optimizer choose a different path, as the main cost of 0.57..10735.90 seems to be lower than 13137.72..13137.72.
However, I do not understand why the actual time differs so much from the calculated one.
Additionally, the upper costs are dramatically higher (34803947.27 vs 13105.30), thus the optimizer should (at least IMO) see somehow that this won't scale in the long run.
I've tried to:

Run VACUUM ANALYZE on the table manually, no changes (above query plans are the ones after running it).
Played around with work_mem (defaults to 4MB) with no improvements.
Played around with effective_cache_size (defaults to 266313056kB) with no improvements.

Are there other ways to fix this or to improve the optimizer?
I've got the following environment:

PostgreSQL: 14.10
Running in AWS as an RDS Aurora PostgreSQL database, deployed with the AWS CDK

As I'm using Django 4.2 as the application framework, I would prefer any solutions which can be used with its standard ORM.

This is answered here.

@LaurenzAlbe Thanks for the link! I'll take a look at it right away. Unfortunately, in the real world the table has other columns as well (e.g. updated_at) and this issue will arise again just if sorted by those columns depending on what is requested through the API.
Additionally, it will affect a lot of different tables/models and just adding a multi-column index for all use-cases/columns on all tables seems a bit ... unpractical.

We can only answer the questions we get asked...
